# How to map a myBatis result to multiple objects?

Tags: orm, mapping, ibatis, mybatis

Is it possible in myBatis 3 to map a single result to multiple objects, ensuring that the objects all reference the same instance? Is there an example of this I could reference?

**Updated to add more detail:**

For instance, let's say I store information regarding `Contact`s for my application in my DB. I want to know if it's possible to use myBatis to map the same instance of a contact to, say, a `Listing` class, which holds a `Contact`:

```
public class Listing {
    private Contact myContact;
    //getters & setters...
}
```

as well as to a `ContactsHolder` class, which also holds a `Contact`:

```
public class ContactsHolder {
    private Contact aContact
    //getters & setters...
}
```

I need the object that is mapped by myBatis to both the `Listing` and `ContactsHolder` classes to be the same instance. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give more information on the problem your trying to solve?  The result mapping in MyBatis 3 is extremely powerful, it does a lot.

Comment: @AndyPryor: I have updated my question for more detail as to the problem I'm trying to solve. I hope this helps clarify what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to get an instance of "Listing" and and instance of "ContactsHolder" is one database call?

Comment: @AndyPryor: Yes, though it doesn't have to be in one database call necessarily. As long as the instance of the `Contact` that is mapped in both classes is the same, that's I all need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MyBatis isn't able to do that with standard result mapping. (at least to my knowledge).  You could select the "Contact" object, then build a Listing and ContactsHolder manually with both of them referencing the Contact.

Or implement a custom ResultSetHandler.

It's kind of a peculiar request,  I'm not sure why you want the same instances shared across two objects like that.  That's probably why no feature like this exists in MyBatis 3.

Comment: BTW, I was able to solve this using a myBatis plugin (pg. 17 of the [User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf&can=3&q=Docs)) and intercepting the `handleResultSets` method in the `ResultSetHandler` class. I was able to add the same `Contact` instance contained in the result set to both my `Listing` and `ContactsHolder` classes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with standard result mapping if you use select to fetch the associated contact and both objects are fetched in the same session.

Modify result maps for `Listing` and `ContactsHolder`:

```
<resultMap type="Listing" id="listingMap">
   <association property="myContact" column="contact_id" javaType="Contact" select="selectContact"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="ContactsHolder" id="contactsHolderMap">
   <association property="aContact" column="contact_id" javaType="Contact" select="selectContact"/>
</resultMap>
```

Now create a query `selectContact`:

```
<select id='selectContact' resultType='Contact'>
     SELECT * from contact where id = #{id}
</select>
```

Now if you create some select that uses both `listingMap` and `contactsHolderMap` to map `Listing` and `ContactsHolder` records that reference the same contact they will both query for the contact using the same id.

Mybatis uses local cache for all objects read in a session so during fetching of the second associated contact the cache will be hit and the same object will be reused.

Even if you do two queries manually to get `Listing` and `ContactsHolder` in the *same transaction* the same `Contact` will be used in both returned objects.